Flutter Firebase Analytics Error: Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentStatusDenied
I am trying to implement firebase analytics and crashlytics to my flutter project but I am getting the error below when I try to run on iOS simulator and physical device:
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentStatusDenied

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentStatusGranted

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentTypeAdPersonalization

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentTypeAdStorage

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentTypeAdUserData

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _FIRConsentTypeAnalyticsStorage

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.

I tried some different solutions like adding arm64 to Excluded Architectures or updating/clearing pods etc. but nothing helped.
I followed official docs (ie. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics). Here is some information about my environment, my pubspec file and my podfile
Flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.3, on macOS 14.4.1 23E224 darwin-arm64, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.19.3 on channel stable at /Users/taha/Dev/core/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ba39319843 (2 months ago), 2024-03-07 15:22:21 -0600
    • Engine revision 2e4ba9c6fb
    • Dart version 3.3.1
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/taha/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34-ext8, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15E204a
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.88.0

pubspec dependencies
dependencies:
  adjust_sdk: ^4.31.0
  android_id: ^0.3.6
  animate_do: ^3.0.2
  auto_route: ^7.8.4
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
  bloc: ^8.1.2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  cached_network_svg_image: ^0.0.7
  chewie: ^1.8.1
  collection: 1.18.0
  connectivity_plus: ^5.0.2
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  device_info_plus: ^9.0.3
  dio: ^5.3.2
  dropdown_button2: ^2.3.9
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  expandable: ^5.0.1
  file_picker: ^6.1.1
  firebase_analytics: ^10.10.5
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.5.5
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
  flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.2
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.2
  flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_notification_channel: ^3.1.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
  flutter_slidable: ^3.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.9
  get_ip_address: ^0.0.6
  get_it: ^7.6.4
  hive: ^2.2.3
  html: ^0.15.4
  http: ^1.1.0
  image_cropper: ^5.0.1
  image_gallery_saver: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^1.0.2
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^4.0.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  keep_screen_on: ^3.0.0
  keyboard_actions: ^4.2.0
  local_auth: ^2.1.7
  mqtt_client: ^10.0.3
  overlay_support: ^2.1.0
  package_info_plus: ^7.0.0
  path: ^1.8.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.12
  pdf: ^3.10.8
  pdfx:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/ScerIO/packages.flutter
      ref: 8b105a7dfc6b90220c1d79fcb805fb764cab00c5
      path: packages/pdfx
  pinput: ^3.0.1
  protoc_plugin: ^21.0.2
  readmore: ^2.2.0
  share_plus: ^7.2.1
  shimmer: ^3.0.0
  skeletonizer: ^1.0.1
  sqflite: ^2.3.0
  sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2
  syncfusion_flutter_charts: 23.1.44
  syncfusion_flutter_datagrid: 23.1.44
  syncfusion_flutter_gauges: 23.1.44
  talker: ^4.0.2
  talker_bloc_logger: ^4.0.2
  talker_dio_logger: ^4.0.2
  talker_flutter: ^4.0.2
  toast: ^0.3.0
  turkish: ^0.2.1
  tw_queue: ^0.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.2.4
  video_player: ^2.7.2
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.0
  wolt_modal_sheet: ^0.1.4

Podfile
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '14.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'Toaster'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '6.5.16'
  pod 'EnVerify', '1.3.14.5'
  
#  $FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = false
end

def remove_duplicated_frameworks(app_pod_name, installer)
  test_targets = get_test_targets(app_pod_name, installer)
  puts "Detected test targets: #{test_targets}"

  puts "Removing duplicated frameworks from OTHER_LDFLAGS"
  targets = installer.aggregate_targets.select { |x| !test_targets.include?(x.name) }
  puts " targets: #{targets}"
  # Checks each pair of targets if they have common pods. Duplicates are removed from the first one's xcconfig.
  for i in 0..targets.size-1 do
      target = targets[i]
      puts " target: #{target}"
      remainingAppPodTargets = target.pod_targets
      puts " remainingAppPodTargets: #{remainingAppPodTargets}"
      target.xcconfigs.each do |config_name, config_file|
          # Removes all frameworks which exist in other pods
         
          remainingAppPodTargets
              .flat_map {|pod_target| get_framework_names(pod_target)}
              .each { |framework| config_file.frameworks.delete(framework) }
             
          # Saves updated xcconfig
          xcconfig_path = target.xcconfig_path(config_name)
          config_file.save_as(xcconfig_path)
      end
  end
end

def get_test_targets(app_pod_name, installer)
  main_target_name = app_pod_name.gsub("Pods-", "")

  installer.aggregate_targets
      .find { |x| x.name == app_pod_name }
      .user_project
      .targets
      .select { |x| x.test_target_type? }
      .flat_map { |x| ["Pods-#{x}", "Pods-#{main_target_name}-#{x}"] }
      .select { |x| installer.aggregate_targets.map(&:name).include?(x) }
      .uniq
end

def get_framework_names(pod_target)
  frameworkNames = pod_target.specs.flat_map do |spec|
      # We should take framework names from 'vendored_frameworks'.
      # If it's not defined, we use 'spec.name' instead.
      #
      # spec.name can be defined like Framework/Something - we take the first part
      # because that's what appears in OTHER_LDFLAGS.
      puts " spec: #{spec}"
      frameworkPaths = unless spec.attributes_hash['ios'].nil?
          then spec.attributes_hash['ios']['vendored_frameworks']
          else spec.attributes_hash['vendored_frameworks']
          end || [spec.name.split(/\//, 2).first]

      map_paths_to_filenames(frameworkPaths)
  end

  frameworkNames.uniq
end

def map_paths_to_filenames(paths)
  Array(paths).map(&:to_s).map do |filename|
      extension = File.extname filename
      File.basename filename, extension
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'No'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    target.xcconfigs.each do |variant, xcconfig|
    xcconfig_path = target.client_root + target.xcconfig_relative_path(variant)
    IO.write(xcconfig_path, IO.read(xcconfig_path).gsub("DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR", "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"))
    end
  end
  remove_duplicated_frameworks('Pods-Runner', installer)
end

Thanks for your helps

have you tried configuring your project with Flutterfire?

Yes, I tried twice

In Xcode press on the runner (targets) then navigate to the build phase tab, delete the flutterfire crashlytics config, and try again.

no luck, still getting same errors

Facing similar issue, plus
Undefined symbol: _main
I am running a new ios native app after integrating the ios-framework created out of a flutter module

In my case it was recently added
"OTHER_LDFLAGS[arch=*]" = "-ObjC";

in ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj buildSettings.
Removing it solved the error

sorry for the late response but no luck, still throwing the same error
